# implementing protocols in AppDelegate.m: "prefix attribute must be followed by an interface or protocol"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am adding two protocols to AppDelegate so that I can swap root view controllers. I did this in a previous project (2 months ago) like so and it worked fine:

```
@interface AppDelegate () <ChangeRootController1, ChangeRootController2>

@end
```

So I did the same in today's project, but then all my functions give this error:

Missing context for method declaration

So I tried this:

```
@interface AppDelegate () AppDelegate <ChangeRootController1, ChangeRootController2>

@end
```

And now I get

```
Prefix attribute must be followed by an interface or protocol
```

What's the proper way to make AppDelegate.m conform to protocols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first snippet is correct - there's nothing wrong in doing:

```
@interface AppDelegate () <ChangeRootController1, ChangeRootController2>

@end
```

I think the error is misleading you. Have you made sure to place your method declarations (e.g. of those protocols) between `@implementation AppDelegate` and `@end`?

Comment: you are correct, but I didn't have to put the method declarations in - rather I rebuilt a few times once you told me this was correct, and eventually the error went away.

Comment: I am glad you got it working. Remember to do a "Clean" or "Clean Build Folder.." when you experience issues where you have good reasons for why it is not supposed to act this way.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the second code block you added there. The first one is right!

The thing that is missing is that you have some methods (probably those one required by `ChangeRootController1` `ChangeRootController2`) outside your implementation block. Your method definitions should always be inside the implementation block of the owner class.

```
@interface AppDelegate () AppDelegate <ChangeRootController1, ChangeRootController2>

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

//methods go here

@end
```